# .attr("href") with links containing commas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hay i have a link like this

```
index.php?sometext=f,fsdsd,rerw,e,wewewe
```

and when i use .attr("href") on the link, it stops at the first comma, so it only displays

```
index.php?sometext=f
```

Any idea how to get ALL the href value

Comment: > *it stops at the first comma*  No it doesn't: http://jsbin.com/ajumu

Comment: Works for me... You might be doing something else wrong, could you show us more code?

Comment: Probably it's browser dependant. What browser do you use to test?

Comment: @Ivan: FF2, FF3, Chrome 2, Chrome 4, Chrome 5, Safari 4, IE 6, Opera 10. Browsers are very forgiving about parsing markup like this.

Comment: @Roatin: Yes, it looks like problem is somewhere else in the code? (I've also checked it in IE8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace `,` with `%2C` in your links. This is [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Answer (score 0):

Commas are among the characters that should be [urlencoded](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) when present in a URL, that is, in their case, replaced with `%2C`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').each(function(i, el){

    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    if (href.split('?').length == 2) {
        var dir = href.split('?')[0], query = href.split('?')[1];
        $(this).attr('href', dir + '?' + encodeURI(query));
    }

});
```

[encodeURI](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/)